# CASE STATEMENT for create view in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a create view query and I want to check if it does not exist yet, then create view. I tried to create like this:

```
CASE WHEN IS NOT EXISTS vw_Delays
THEN
VIEW vw_Delays AS
SELECT RD_RfileID_fk_ind, SUM(DATEDIFF(day, RD_Startdate, RD_EndDate)) AS delays FROM dbo.t_RfDelay
GROUP BY RD_RfileID_fk_ind
END
```

but it returns these errors:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CASE'.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
>   Incorrect syntax near 'END'.

How to solve this? Please can anyone help me to fix this ?

Comment: CASE in SQL is an expression rather than an statement.  Expressions return a value, while statements are used to control flow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use this code to check for the view's existence:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.views WHERE Name = N'vw_Delays')
   .....
```

The next obstacle you'll encounter is the fact that the `CREATE VIEW` statement must be the first of a SQL batch - so you *cannot* have it right after the existence check.

What I usually do is the opposite:

- check if the view *does* exist
- and if so - drop the existing view
- then create the view from scratch

and I use this code for this setup:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.views WHERE Name = N'vw_Delays')
   DROP VIEW dbo.vw_Delays;
GO

CREATE VIEW dbo.vw_Delays 
AS
   SELECT 
       RD_RfileID_fk_ind, 
       SUM(DATEDIFF(day, RD_Startdate, RD_EndDate)) AS delays 
   FROM 
       dbo.t_RfDelay
   GROUP BY 
       RD_RfileID_fk_ind
```